# OAConsumer API thows an error on receive data

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth, google-oauth

I'm trying to fetch data using OAConsumer API. I tried the following code which threw me an error.

```
-(void)performQuery
{
 OAConsumer *consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc] initWithKey:OAUTH_KEY
                                                  secret:OAUTH_SECRET];

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.semantics3.com/v1/products"];

 OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                                               consumer:consumer
                                                                  token:nil   
                                                                  realm:nil  
                                                      signatureProvider:nil]; // use the default method, HMAC-SHA1

  [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
  [consumer release];


  OARequestParameter * qParam = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"q" value:@"{\"cat_id\":13658,\"model\":\"Satellite\"}"];


 NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:qParam, nil];
 [qParam release];

 [request setParameters:params];
 OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];

 [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                     delegate:self
            didFinishSelector:@selector(requestDidFinishWithData:)
              didFailSelector:@selector(requestDidFailWithError:)];

  [request release];
```

}

The error is as follows:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[OAServiceTicket bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ed65bf0'
```

The error happens on this line:
         ****NSString *response= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];***

```
  - (void)requestDidFinishWithData:(NSData *)data {

    NSString *response= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //here do what you want with the response, I use SBJson to parse it.

    NSLog(@"Request success!%@", response); 
    [responseBody release];


 }


  - (void)requestDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"Request did fail with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

  }
```

Any idea what I'm doing here?

Comment: I've got the exact same problem. Evidently the OAServiceTicket object doesnt exist anymore. I havent been able to find an ARC iOS version of this project as of yet and perhaps all of the non-ARC stuff is causing some issues. Did you get it fixed yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read as NSData when it is actually an OAServiceTicket object.

An OAServiceTicket object has the following:

```
request = [aRequest retain];
response = [aResponse retain];
data = [aData retain];
didSucceed = success;
```

So your delegate has to be as follows:

```
- (void)requestDidFinishWithData:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket {

    NSString *response= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:ticket.data
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //here do what you want with the response, I use SBJson to parse it.

    NSLog(@"Request success!%@", response);
    [response release];

}
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

please whether the ticket is success, like this...

```
 - (void)fetchingVideoTicket:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinishWithData:(NSData *)data{
if(ticket.didSucceed)
{
  your code...
 }
```

it seem in your case the request is success but there is no response generated which states that you have not included all the required parameters for that request, i also got the same problem when i tried to connect with Vimeo but after i added the callback parameter to the request, the connection is successful and response is generated. Check whether you have added all the parameters.